# Inflation Index

Tags: economics

The inflation index of a country $A$ in $1995$ relative to $1990$ was $5$. Meaning that the ratio of dollars spent during $1990$ for goods compared to dollars spent for same goods is $1:5$. In country $B$ the inflation index is $9$ for the same period. In country $C$ the inflation index is $1$3. A pair of shoe cost $ \$72$ more in $1995$ than in $1990$ in all three countries. What was the ration between the price of pair of shoe in country $A,B,C$ in $1995$.

I cant get the concept of inflation index.

Comment: It means that if something cost one dollar in each country in 1990, then in 1995, it cost five dollars in $A$, nine in $B$, and 13 in $C$.

Comment: in the first line, "relative to 1990" is it?

Comment: Yes sorry for the typo its edited

Comment: the answer is 30:27:26

Answer (score 1):

Let the cost of the shoe be x , y , z in country A, B , C respectively in 1990.      In 1995, they became  5x, 9y, 13z   due to inflation(that's what the index meant). Now, the difference is 4x, 8y, 12z which is all the same 72$ .   From this, x=18 ; y= 9 ; z=6 ;     5x=90; 9y = 81; 13z= 78    ;   ans- 90:81:78 = 30:27:26